# Why is $\{(x,y) \mid x,y\in\mathbb{C}\}$ an infinite dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{Q}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

$V=\{(x,y)\mid x,y \in \mathbb{C}\}$ is a vector space over $\mathbb{C}$, $\mathbb{R}$, and $\mathbb{Q}$. Then $\operatorname{dim} (V)=2$ over $\mathbb{C}$, and $4$ over $\mathbb{R}$, but why it is infinite over $\mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: It's uncountable.

Comment: A vector space with countable dimension over a countable field is countable. In your case, $\mathbb{C}^2$ is an uncountable space, so the dimension has to be uncountable and infinite.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the notation. $\mathbb{Q}^2$ has dimension $2$, so what is meant here?

Comment: Hint: what is the dimension of $\mathbb{R}$ as a $\mathbb{Q}$-vector space? Because the dimension of $\mathbb{C}^2$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ will be four times as big.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that it were a finite-dimensional space of dimension $n \in \Bbb N$.
Let $B = \{v_1, \ldots, v_n\} \subset \Bbb C^2$ be a basis.

Then, every $v \in \Bbb C^2$ could be written as $$v = q_1z_1 + \cdots + q_nz_n$$ for some unique choice of scalars $q_1, \ldots, q_n$.
This gives us an injection $\Bbb C^2 \to \Bbb Q^n$ defined by
$$v \mapsto (q_1, \ldots, q_n).$$

This would give us a contradiction since $\Bbb C^2$ is uncountable whereas $\Bbb Q^n$ is not.

---

With a bit more effort, one can show that no countable basis exists either. For this, you may have to use the fact that the set of finite subsets of $\Bbb Q$ is countable.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: a finite-dimensional (or even countable-dimensional) space over a countable field is countable.

Answer (score -1):

You can see the dimension of a vector space $V$ over a field $\Bbb F$ as the number of parameters $a,b,c,... \in \Bbb F$ you need to use in order to write a generic element of $V$. Examples:

You can write every $(x,y)\in V$ as $(a,b)$ with $a,b\in \Bbb C$. $a$ and $b$ are **2** complex parameters so the dimension of $V$ over $\Bbb C$ is 2.

You can also write every complex number $a+bi$ with $a,b\in \Bbb R$. But to write every element $(x,y)\in V$ you need **two** complex numbers, so you can write it as $(a+bi, c+di)$ with $a,b,c,d\in \Bbb R$. You need **4** real parameters so the dimension of $V$ over $\Bbb R$ is 4.

How many **rational** parameters do you need to write every element of $V$?
If we say two and write $(x,y)\in V$ as $(a,b)$ with $a,b\in \Bbb Q$ we can find at least one element of $V$ that cannot be written by using just two rational numbers: $(π, i)$. Is this an element of $V$? Yes. But π is irrational so you need to sum an *infinite* number of rational parameters to represent it. **(EDIT)>>** So you must add it to a basis of $V$, so the dimension is three, at least. You can always find an irrational number with this same property and you'll have to add it to a basis of $V$. Since the *linearly independent* irrational numbers are infinitely many, the dimension of $V$ over $\Bbb Q$ is infinite.

Comment: Your answer isn't quite correct. For example, the field $\Bbb Q(\sqrt{2})$ viewed as a vector space over $\Bbb Q$ is finite-dimensional but it does contain an irrational number, namely $\sqrt{2}$. (To be precise - "But $\pi$ is irrational so you need to sum an *infinite* number of rational parameters to represent it." is what I had a problem with.)

Comment: @AryamanMaithani in that case $\sqrt{2}$ is **very** particular, just like $i$ in $\Bbb C$. The fact that it is irrational is not a problem there because it's an element of the set **by definition**, while in my answer the fact that you can't express it as sum of rational numbers is actually the reason why the dimension of $V$ is infinite. In other words, obviously it still has that property but **being a problem** or not highly depends on the context.

Comment: $\pi$ not being expressible as a sum of (finitely many) rational numbers has got nothing to do with the dimension, though.

Comment: @AryamanMaithani By the way, quick question: is it true that $\pi \in \Bbb Q(\sqrt 2)$?

Comment: No, that is not.

Comment: And could you write a basis of $\Bbb Q(\sqrt 2)$?

Comment: $\{1, \sqrt{2}\}$ would be one.

Comment: In fact, just consider $\Bbb R$ as a vector space over $\Bbb Q$, pick your favourite irrationals (finitely many) and consider the subspace spanned by them. That'll be a finite vector space over $\Bbb Q$.

Comment: How many rational parameters do you need to write $\sqrt 2$ as linear combination of that basis?

Comment: "rational parameters" doesn't seem like a well defined term but note that $$\sqrt{2} = 0\cdot1 + 1 \cdot \sqrt{2}.$$ So I guess two "parameters".

Comment: I agree with you, absolutely. And can you write a basis of $\Bbb C^2$, considered as a vector space over $\Bbb Q$?

Comment: I'm afraid I have no *choice* but to say that I cannot.

Comment: Please check my answer again.

Comment: The argument still doesn't go very well. For example, "having infinite irrationals" is not enough. You need infinitely many *linearly independent* irrationals. For example, consider constructing a basis (of $\Bbb R$) which has $\pi$ and $e$. Once you have those, you don't have to worry about adding $\pi + \dfrac{1}{5}e$, for example. In fact, my earlier example of $\Bbb Q(\sqrt 2)$ also contains infinitely many irrationals but is still a finite dimensional space.

Comment: Right, of course that's what I meant.

Comment: Right, that seems better now. (Except it doesn't seem obvious to me to directly show that there are infinitely many linearly independent irrationals without a cardinality argument or something similar.)

Comment: If I have to prove that "there are infinitely many linearly independent irrationals" in my answer, you have to prove that "$\Bbb C^2$ is uncountable while $\Bbb Q^n$ is not" in yours. Just saying the word "uncountable" *doesn't count* as an argument. (If the OP asked for it I'd write a proof for that, of course.)

Comment: When I had started linear algebra, I was aware of facts about cardinalities of different sets. The difference between our answers is that a reader unfamiliar with this particular topic could understand my argument by "accepting" more "standard" facts. (In fact, uncountability is something reasonable to expect the reader to be familiar with.) Of course, you may disagree with this. (By the way, I still think it would be easier to demonstrate the uncountability of $\Bbb Q$ than to explicitly show an infinite set of linearly independent irrationals (with proof).)

Comment: That is, in fact, a mere opinion I disagree with, since this exact concept has been explained to me the way I explained it in my answer and at the time I wasn't expected to know why $\Bbb C^2$ is uncountable. Let's stop it here.